# Obter valor do atributo SRC de uma imagem dentro do DIV

Tags: php

Tenho uma div que tem uma  imagem cadastrada e o problema é o seguinte: somente desta tag div que tem id através deste id do div que preciso saber o endereço da imagem que está no src.

Exemplo:

```
<div id="output"> <img src="/images/blog/outra-imagem-C.jpg" /> </div>
```

Ou seja, faço a busca pelo id="output" e ele me retorna o endereço src="/images/blog/cliente-ideal-voce-sabe-quem-e.jpg".

Tentei utilizar o DOMDocument

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$img = $dom->getElementById("output");

echo $img->getAttribute("src"), PHP_EOL;
```

Porém sem sucesso pois deveria utilizar a

> getElementByTagName com o IMG

Porém preciso pegar através do ID da DIV.

Observação: Aceito solução em PHP.

Comment: Por que PHP? Essa verificação deverá ser executada no servidor? O que precisa fazer com esta imagem?

Comment: Sim, isso você disse na pergunta, mas por que precisa da solução em PHP? O que justificará utilizar essa linguagem? O que precisará fazer com esse valor que justifica fazer essa verificação no servidor?

Comment: Ué, desistiu que pudesse ser em JavaScript também?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss respondi baseado na tag que vi na primeira edição, eu nem vi se houve outras devido a algumas edições rapidas não aparecerem :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ele havia comentado que poderia ser em JS quando questionei o que justificaria usar PHP. Parece que ele excluiu o comentário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você esta tentando pegar o src do DIV e não da imagem, se o `getElementById` retorna o elemento DIV, então você tem que executar no contexto do DIV `getElementsByTagName('img')`, assim vai pegar qualquer elemento descendente que seja do tipo `<img>`, ficando assim:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$divOutput = $dom->getElementById("output");

foreach ($divOutput->getElementsByTagName('img') as $el) {
    var_dump( $el->getAttribute('src') );
}
```

Para pegar apenas a primeira ocorrencia basta usar um IF, assim:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$divOutput = $dom->getElementById("output");

if (!$divOutput) {
    echo '#output não encontrado';
} else {
    $imgs = $divOutput->getElementsByTagName('img');

    if (!$imgs->length) {
         echo 'Não há imagens dentro de #output';
    } else {
         var_dump( $imgs[0]->getAttribute('src') );
    }
}
```

O `$imgs[0]` pegará somente a primeira ocorrência.

Comment: Perfeito!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!